# CoraData fetch over multiple relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am having problems with CoreData and I know part of it is because I'm very familiar with database programming and CoreData as I have read several places, is not a database.  I guess part of the problem is it seems to walk like a cow and quack like a duck and that's frustrating me.

I'm working through the Stanford class on one of the flickrfetcher exercises.
I want to get all the photos from a particular region.
I have three entities of importance to this example.

**Region**

*Attributes*

- region_ID
- region_Name
- photoQty

*Relationships*

- hasLocations

**Location**

*Attributes*

- location_ID
- location_name
- photoQty

*Relationships*

- isInRegion
- hasPhotos

**Photo**

*Attributes*

- photo_ID
- photo_title

*Relationships*

- ofLocation

There are other entities and other attributes and relationships, but they are not relevant to this discussion.

I am populating a tableview of photo_title's and want to fetch all the photos from a particular region.  So I'm trying to

```
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Photo"];
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:NO]];

request.predicate=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY ofLocation.isInRegion.regionName=%@",self.regionName];
NSError *error;
NSArray *photoResults = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

I'm getting `.768 FlickrRegions[2592:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath name not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Photo id=3>`

I'm guessing it's because of the predicate, but I have not been able to find a good explanation of how to setup what to coreData is evidently a complex predicate.

As a second part.  Can someone point me to a good explanation of coredata (not the apple documentation please) and subqueries.  The solutions I have found to this seem to either say to break it up into multiple queries or use subqueries and I have not found a source for information about subqueries.

Thanks,
Chip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because you are trying to sort photos by `name` while there is not such a property. From you description I see that `Photo` has `photo_title` property, so adjust your sort descriptor to:

```
request.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"photo_title" ascending:NO]];
```

Comment: OMG.  I can't believe I missed that.  I could have sworn I commented that out.  I've been grabbing the same chunk of code every time I have to do a new query and changing/commenting what I don't need.  Thanks and so sorry to waste your time.